# What's the SwiftUI equivalent of touchesBegan(_:with:)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want a timer to start running as soon as I touch the screen, and I when I lift my finger off the screen, the timer should stop.

I can't find anything, anywhere, remotely close to resembling/implementing this simple task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a (somewhat crude but functional) example.

Note that the gesture is attached to a view that is essentially defining your tap area (in this case the whole screen minus safe areas). It could easily be the `Text` scaled to match the screen as well but I used a `ZStack` to make it more clear.

I guess the most relevant part to your question is the `onChanged/onEnded` closures.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var counter  = 0
    @State var touching = false

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            Text("\(counter)")
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { input in
            guard self.touching else { return }
            self.counter += 1
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onChanged { _ in
            self.touching = true
        }.onEnded { _ in
            self.touching = false
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution on a `TabView` with `PageTabViewStyle` but it didn't work as expected. My timer changes the selected page programmatically after 3 seconds using `withAnimation`. I wanted to detect if the user started a drag gesture to manually change the page to stop my timer, then resume the timer when the user lift the finger. This solution prevents the user from flipping the pages. Is there a way to make this gesture not interfere with other system gestures like swiping on a page view? Thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue as @alabaili  did you find any solution to this problem using a tabview?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue like @alobaili, did you find the solution for it?

Comment: i too have the exact same issue, will keep you posted if i find a fix